# How to declare multiple variables using a loop?

Tags: bash

Is it possible to define n assign a value to multiple variables using a loop??

I was trying to achieve something like the following.

```
for (( i=0, i<=10, i++ )) 
do 
var_$i="value"
done
```

upon execution,  it throws something like command not found...

thanks.

Comment: in which language you are trying this?

Comment: Save your sanity and use an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would be better off with [arrays](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html). That said, you can do:

```
for (( i=0; i<=10; i++ )) 
do 
    eval "var_${i}='value'"
done

echo $var_3
```

with array:

```
for i in $(seq 1 10); do
  array[$i]=$(($i * $i))
done
echo ${array[7]} # -> 49
```

---

As rici notes in the comments, also consider:

> ```
> declare var_$i="$value"
> ```

Comment: @alper Feel free to add that as a side note to the answer (or post a different answer if you feel like it) :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution...  will try this out...  I had tried using arrays...  but the outcome wasn't as expected...     i.e var1="x" .....  arrx=("var1")... so  $var1 would be x and the $${arrx[0]} would be something else....     please forgive the way I typed..  using a phone right now...

Comment: `eval` forces you to figure out how to quote `value` for double-expansion. Better is `declare var_$i="$value"` (also less subject to injection attack)